# How would I do this set partition problem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

A = {red, blue, green, purple} 
B = {red, red, green}

Let E = {blue, red, green, purple, orange, black} and Let F = {black, orange}, do A, B, F form a partition of E? If not, which condition of a partition is not satisfied?
I'd say yes because the resulting partitions would be: 
{ red, blue, green, purple, black, orange }
{ red, blue, green, purple}, { black, orange }
{ red, blue, green, purple, black, orange }, { red, green }
{ red, blue, green, purple }, { red, green, black, orange }
{ red, blue, green, purple }, { red, green }, { black, orange }
Which contains a set that is equal to set E. 
I'm probably doing this wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the sets $A$, $B$, and $F$ would form a partition of $E$ if the following three conditions were satisfied:

- $A\cup B\cup F = E$
- None of $A$, $B$, or $F$ is the empty set,
- The intersection of any two of these three sets must be empty.

Are all three of these conditions satisfied for your sets?

Comment: The third bullet is not satisfied since set A and B would have intersection is not empty. Would that make the whole statement false?

Comment: That's exactly right